# Abrir un fichero o archivo con determinado programa mediante la consola - Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, línea-de-comandos

Hola quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de abrir un archivo con determinada aplicación mediante la linea de comandos ya sea mediante la cracion de un alias o algún otro método, pondré un ejemplo de que quiero abrir un archivo llamado "index.html" pero no lo deseo abrir con vin o con nano, pero si con el editor de texto Atom.

En resumen, es abrir un archivo con una aplicación que nosotros definamos mediante un alias o algo similar.

Les agradecería mucho su respuesta :D

Answer (score 1):

#### Visualmente

`Click derecho sobre el archivo -> propiedades` te dirá con qué se abre esa extensión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si selecciono Visual Studio (no tengo atom instalado) las propiedades de otros html te dirán que ahora se abre con ese programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ese lugar puedes seleccionar otra de las aplicaciones que aparezcan para dejarla asociada por defecto, y puedes añadir otras apps para que te las sugiera cuando aplicas *click derecho -> abrir con*

Dependiendo de la versión de Ubuntu hay otra sección de "Preferred Applications" que puedes abrir con

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

(Esa utilidad es parte de XFCE, pero puedes instalarla con `sudo apt install exo-utils`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### Por línea de comando

En algunos casos hay acciones que invocan al browser por defecto, o bien el editor por defecto. ¿Cuál es el browser por defecto? No necesariamente es el browser al que le pusiste `set as default browser`. Yo tengo Firefox, aquí dice bien claro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si pincho un link en la consola se abre chromium... Qué está pasando? En realidad  El comportamiento del sistema será llamar al ejecutable que aparezca en `/etc/alternatives/`

Veamos qué dice ahí:

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives | egrep 'browser|editor'

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  editor -> /usr/bin/vim.basic*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/leafpad*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  gnome-www-browser -> /usr/bin/firefox*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  x-www-browser -> /usr/bin/chromium-browser*
```

Ajá. Hay que cambiar el dichoso `x-www-browser`-

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser

There are 4 choices for the alternative x-www-browser 
(providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable   200       manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/chromium-browser       40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/google-chrome-beta     150       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide
/usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in manual mode
```

Ahora en `/etc/alternatives` dice:

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives | egrep 'browser|editor'

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  editor -> /usr/bin/vim.basic*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/leafpad*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  gnome-www-browser -> /usr/bin/firefox*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  x-www-browser -> /usr/bin/firefox*
```

#### Y las url con protocolo custom?

Hay otro tipo de asociaciones que no corresponden a una extensión de archivo sino, por ejemplo, al mime type con que el browser asociará un handler. Tal es el caso de la asociación de las url de tipo `magnet` como:

```
 magnet:?xt=urn:btih:c12fe1c06bba254a9dc9f519b335aa7c1367a88a
```

Ese tipo de asociaciones "url-scheme" están declaradas en

```
  ~/.local/share/applications
```

que son configuraciones locales para tu usuario y en

```
  /usr/share/applications
```

Que son globales para todos los usuarios (tu configuración local tiene prioridad)

En particular, las asociaciones *url-scheme* como las que mencioné debieran estar en:

```
 ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

O en

```
 ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Ahí yo tengo, por ejemplo:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/magnet=qBittorent.desktop
text/x-arduino=arduino-arduinoide.desktop
```

Esos archivos con extensión `.desktop` residen en la misma carpeta y hacen alusión a un ejecutable definiendo además su ícono y listando qué extensiones y mimetypes saben abrir.

---

#### Y si no existe ese `.desktop`?

Si quisieras abrir una determinada extensión o mimetype que no tiene default, y no hay un `.desktop` en esa carpeta o en la carpeta global, puedes crear ese `.desktop` tú mismo. Digamos que no aparece Postman, y tú quieres que el browser abra esa app cuando pinches un link del tipo

```
postman://app/collections/import/631643-dac5eac9-148d-a32e-b76b-3edee9da28f7-JsLs
```

(para cuando quieres correrla en ese programa con el famoso botón "Run In Postman")

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tuvieras un `.desktop` bastaría declararlo en `defaults.list` o `mimetypes.list`:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/magnet=qBittorent.desktop
text/x-arduino=arduino-arduinoide.desktop
x-scheme-handler/postman=postman.desktop
```

Pero si ese `.desktop` no existe, tú puedes crearlo.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Postman
Exec=postman        <------- puede ser la ruta absoluta, pero falta algo...
Icon=/opt/Postman/app/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
```

Pero así como está puesto, pinchar un link cuyo mimetype está asociado a la aplicación la abrirá en blanco y no con el contenido del link. ¿Por qué? En esos casos puedes ver cómo se invoca esa app desde el launcher:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y verás que se le pasa como parámetro la colección que quieres abrir (o el torrent, o el archivo) así que el ejecutable debiera ser declarado como

```
Exec=postman %U
```

---

#### Y las acciones específicas de un programa?

Cuando haces por ejemplo `git commit archivo.java` git abre un editor donde puedes dejar el mensaje. Lo mismo cuando haces `git rebase -i [commit]` te abre el mismo editor con los commits para que los cambies de orden, hagas un squash, o los elimines. ¿Dónde se configura ese editor o, por ejemplo, la herramienta de merge/resolución de conflictos?

Ese tipo de configuraciones suele estar en la configuración específica de la aplicación y varía caso a caso, pero en el caso de git, está en `~/.gitconfig`. Ahí dice por ejemplo:

```
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[core]
    editor = nano
```

Pero no quiero editar ese archivo directamente. Mejor preguntarle a git cuál es el editor por defecto

```
 $ git config --global core.editor

 nano
```

Hey pero yo quiero usar vim, así que pongo:

```
 $ git config --global core.editor vim
```

Y luego:

```
 $ git config --global core.editor

 vim
```